# Как приостановить работу JavaScript до нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Я написал функцию, замену встроенным `alert` и `prompt`:

```
function wind(){
код..
//Код кнопки в окне
wndbot.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="   Ok   " onClick="alert(\''+varbl+'\');isok=true;closewin();" title="Принять" id="okbut"><input type="button" value="'+strs[1]+'" onClick="closewin();" title="'+strs[1]+'" id="clsbut">';
и ещё код..
}
function closewin(){
//Код закрытия
}
//Вот пример использования
wind();
var a=5;
```

Надо, чтобы работа JavaScript приостанавливалась до вызова `closewin()`, то есть `a` будет равно 5 только после вызова `closewin()` (как нажатие OK в `prompt` и `alert`), а не сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не в ту сторону копаете, вам всего навсего необходимо прописать обработчик события нажатия кнопки, естественно пока ее не нажмут - ничего происходить не будет...

Какие бы не были сложные задачи разветвления и асинхронности javascript кода  - все можно решить грамотным event observing'ом...

Функцию типа sleep написать можно, достаточно вбить в гугл sleep javascript, но это вас никак не спасет, как уже написал [@Arni](/users/3748/arni) - в JS нужно все делать исходя из событий

Answer (score 2):

JS может остановить только `Ctrl + Alt + Del`. Либо любые другие команды убиения процесса. И я думаю, что вы неправильно спроектировали ваш алгоритм. В JS нужно все делать исходя из событий, и только так. По одному событию должен начаться процесс, по иному - закончиться. И никаких остановок, задержек типа `sleap` нет и быть не должно.

Comment: А как же prompt и alert?

Comment: prompt и alert имеют что-то общее с современными тенденциями построения пользовательских интерфейсов? Или вам нравится стандартный алерт? :). Я выражался образно, исходя из устоявшихся правил построения приложения на JS